# SQL JOIN two tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following two tables:

```
table_A
eID   
1   
2   
3
4
table_B
eID  dID 
1    7   
1    5
2    9   
2    3
4    8
```

I want the result to look like this:

```
eID dID 
1    1
1    7
1    5
2    2
2    9
2    3
4    4
4    8
3    3
```

I was wondering if there is any different way to achieve this than the following:

```
    (SELECT A.eID, A.eID
    FROM table_A AS A)
    UNION
    (SELECT A.eID, B.dID
    FROM table_A AS A
    INNER JOIN table_B AS B
    ON A.eID = B.eID)
```

Comment: what do you mean by better? more efficient, one that works?

Comment: Access does not support using UNION inside a sub-query, that is why I am trying to find a different way to achieve the same results without using UNION.

Comment: Your 2nd union query should be  `ON A.eID = B.eID `, right ? You said  `=B.dID `... Nevertheless I don't really understand the logic behind this. What is the goal ?

Comment: I think I see a way to do it without UNION but could you add 2 more rows to each table and adapt the result so I visualize better? I need to know: **1.** if `Table_A.eID` is unique and/or always in sequence. **2.** If you have a 1-1 relationship between  `Table_A.eID`  and `Table_B.eID`

Comment: @ThomasG I edited the post with additional rows.  Table_A.eID is unique, but not in sequence.  And there is no relationship between the two columns.  Also, the order of the results returned does not matter.

Comment: Now I see better what you want however your UNION query doesn't return exactly that, it will also return a `3|3` record, so what is correct ?

Comment: @ThomasG Sorry I missed that.  It should return 3|3 as well

Answer (score 3):

I think this is more simply written as:

```
SELECT A.eID, A.eID as dID
FROM table_A
UNION ALL
SELECT B.eID, B.dID
FROM table B;
```

But that still isn't allowed for a subquery.  I would recommend using a view (or switching to a database that is more ANSI-compliant ;).

Comment: Although you have indeed all combinations, It doesn't return them in the order he wants , and I am not sure that you can achieve it with any ORDER clause.

Comment: @ThomasG . . . I can't readily discern the ordering in the modified question.

Comment: nope, because he edited the results and told the order has no importance, afterwards ;)